# MVC routes with static Prefix

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-routing

I have two routes in my routeConfig files as follow.

> 1. Route with **admin** prefix which handles request for admin part
> 2. default Route without a prefix, for which I have added a datatoken to map routes in **candidate Area**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "admin",
                    url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    namespaces: new[] { "abc.namespace1" }
                );

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    namespaces: new[] { "abc.namespace2" }
                ).DataTokens.Add("area", "Candidate");
```

But the problem is when i type in a url **localhost/MyApp/Admin/Home/Index**
it is hitting the controller in **abc.namespace1** (which is expected) and **localhost/MyApp/Home/Index** also hitting Home controller inside **abc.namespace1** instead of HomeController inside **abc.namespace2** in **candidate Area**.

What i want to do here is handle all routes with Admin prefix with controllers inside **abc.namespace1** and all routes without any prefix with controllers inside **abc.namespace2** which is my **candiate Area**.

regards

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might have something to do with the way you have specified your namespaces. The namespace must be for where the controller classes reside.

The pattern is typically `<namespace of area>.<area name>.<controller namespace>`

For example, in a project with an area named "Admin", the namespace must be:

```
"MvcMusicStore.Areas.Admin.Controllers"
```

In my experience, the conventions for how areas are set up are pretty strict. You should not set up the route in an `AreaRegistration` rather than the root of your project in order to get it to work.

```
public class CandidateAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Candidate";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Candidate_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "<project name>.Areas.Candidate.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Areas are convention-based. If you deviate too far from the anticipated conventions, they simply don't function.